# Text and images with jumbotron get distorted when changing screen sizes

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Today i have made a webpage using bootstrap 3, i have change the 'jumbroton' coding to make it look like this: http://www.bootply.com/103783

Although the background image shows through, but when i resize it the page doesn't not resize but instead puts the text and image within the 'jumbotron' underneath something else.

I have tried putting a 'container' around the'jumbotron' with no luck... :(

My website: http://warfacecommunity.bugs3.com/

Try scrolling in and you will see what i meant!

***CSS code in 'style.css'***

```
.bg {
  background: url('/img/BG.jpg') no-repeat center center !important;
  position: fixed !important;
  width: 100% !important;
  height: 350px !important; /*same height as jumbotron */
  top:0 !important;
  left:0 !important;
  z-index: -1 !important;
}

.jumbotron {
  margin-bottom: 40px !important;
  height: 350px !important;
  color: white !important;
  text-shadow: black 0.1em 0.3em 0.3em !important;
  background:transparent !important;
```

***HTML 'Jumbotron'***

```
<div class="jumbotron">
                <img src="./img/the-blue-tick-md.png" alt=" " vspace="20" class="pull-right" class="img-responsive"/>
                <h1>
                    Hello, world!
                </h1>

                <p>
                    This is a template for a simple marketing or informational website. It includes a large callout called the hero unit and three supporting pieces of content. Use it as a starting point to create something more unique.
                </p>
                <p>
                    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-large" href="#">Learn more</a>&nbsp;<a class="btn btn-primary btn-large" href="#">Extras</a>
                </p>
            </div>
```

Comment: I think your .jumbotron height causes issue please try by doing it height:auto;

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 2):

You are very close,

you should divide this in to two parts. and add the jumbotronwidth class for max-width to make it responsive

```
<div class="jumbotron">
<div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 pull-right ">
                <img vspace="20" class="jumbotronwidth" alt=" " src="./img/the-blue-tick-md.png">
</div>
<div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
                <h1>
                    Hello, world!
                </h1>

                <p>
                    This is a template for a simple marketing or informational website. It includes a large callout called the hero unit and three supporting pieces of content. Use it as a starting point to create something more unique.
                </p>
                <p>
                    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-large" href="#">Learn more</a>&nbsp;<a class="btn btn-primary btn-large" href="#">Extras</a>
                </p>
            </div></div>
```

css

```
.jumbotronwidth
{
max-width:100%;
}
```