# Where do I add any custom CSS into a angular-fullstack app?

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, gruntjs, yeoman

I'm looking to add an image into a jumbotron and make it the right width - like in this question: [Bootstrap image to jumbotron width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23267850/bootstrap-3-text-and-images-with-jumbotron-get-distorted-when-changing-screen)

Which is fine but where do I put my custom CSS to make it the right width?

```
.jumbotronwidth
{
    max-width:100%;
}
```

which will then get bundled and minified

Comment: Not sure what you mean.

Comment: Bit of a fail on my part. https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack builds in any css files it finds using injector:css

Answer (score 0):

In your package or system

```
      public/assets/css
             or
      public/system/assets/css
```

which ever folder is present add your `css` files

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way in my opinion is to use LESS for this. You simply create a theme.less and pull in all the original Bootstrap files you want and then in the same file you call your own custom overrides. You'll find this technique explained in [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/594098/How-to-customize-Twitter-Bootstrap-to-fit-your-web) great tutorial.

The benefit of this approach is that LESS compiles to one single CSS file, which will minify without hassle in your current setup. Moreover, this technique allows you to work seperately from your original BS files. Therefore, you can elegantly upgrade that dependency in the future without running into all kinds of trouble.

The alternative - if it's really only this single CSS rule - is to just modify your grunt installation to have it concatenate a small CSS file with your custom rule(s) to your main.css file and minify both of them together. You can do that with [this](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-cssmin#combine-two-files-into-one-output-file) configuration in your cssmin plugin. Or just simply use [Brunch](http://brunch.io) (so much easier :-)